# Why hasn't effects this piece of JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I read a JavaScript book and it gives you a piece of code to run but when I do I don't get anything. It runs but displays nothing.

```
var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
alert("Your number is the square root of " +
  theNumber * theNumber);
```

I'm running this piece of code inside a Harp project, where `_layout.jade` looks like:

```
doctype
html
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css")
  body
    != yield
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and `main.js`

```
var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
alert("Your number is the square root of " +
  theNumber * theNumber);
```

I know that configuration is ok because I've been running another pieces of code before that one. Google Chrome runs the code but doesn't displays any window. I thought it could be adPause but it wasn't. Anyone knows what could it be happening?
Thanks

Comment: Press F12, look in the Console for error messages.

Comment: Runs here: http://jsfiddle.net/3amL7svb/ - are you including the js?

Comment: The path to file.js correct? The code is fine. Even runs in a stack snippet.

Comment: How do you know it runs? What exactly do you mean by "*I checked it with Chrome*"?

Comment: That piece of JavaScript is definitely valid - works fine when I run it.

Comment: I know that the code it's valid and the path to the file.js it is correct. In fact, I've been testing another pieces of code before that one. Chrome console doesn't display any error, just print value `null`, because of `console.log(name)`, but nothing about the prompt.

Comment: I have edit my question, I think now is better, isn't it?

Comment: @Andy, is it now ok?

Comment: @j08691 is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the .js file in chrome, you'll just view it as raw text. You need to include it in a html page, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.onload = function()
            {
                var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
                alert("Your number is the square root of " + (theNumber * theNumber));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- page content, if any -->

    </body>
</html>
```

-- OR --

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- page content, if any -->

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
    alert("Your number is the square root of " + (theNumber * theNumber));
}
```

Comment: Your .js code is not being executed. Put it inside the `window.onload` handler as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I know the code is executed because if I type a console.log, it works